# Labelling a data point in matplotlib using csv data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

First Question so apologies if I mess this up!!

I have csv data like this 3 columns with headers and 10 rows:

| player | pass_att | pass_cmp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dak Prescott | 58 | 42 |
| Tom Brady | 50 | 32 |
| Jalen Hurts | 35 | 27 |
| Matt Ryan | 35 | 21 |
| Ben Roethlisberger | 32 | 18 |
| Josh Allen | 51 | 30 |
| Zach Wilson | 37 | 20 |
| Sam Darnold | 35 | 24 |
| Kirk Cousins | 49 | 36 |
| Joe Burrow | 27 | 20 |

I am reading in the data and producing a graph with the pass attempts as the x-axis and the pass completions as the y-axis and I am trying to use the 'player' column as lables for where my x and y data points intersect.
I have tried using the annotate() function and the text() function but I cannot seem to pass the 'player' column in so it will read the values as text labels.

```
nfl_df = pd.read_csv('nfl2.csv') 
nfl_df = nfl_df.sort_values(by ='pass_att', ascending = False)

np_arr = nfl_df.values
x_2 = np_arr[:, 2]
y_2 = np_arr[:, 1]
#z_2 = nfl_df.column('player')
fig_4 = plt.figure(figsize = (6,4))
axes_4 = fig_4.add_axes([2,2,3,3])

axes_4.set_xlabel('Pass Att')
axes_4.set_ylabel('Pass Cmp')
axes_4.set_title('Pass Att vs Pass Cmp')
axes_4.plot(x_2,y_2,z_2)
axes_4.plot(x_2,y_2, color='cyan', alpha = .90, lw = 2, ls = '-.', marker = 'o', markersize = 7, markerfacecolor = 'b')

#plt.annotate(z_2,(x_2,y_2))
```

[Image of plot so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNfqn.png)

Any help here would be appreciated and thanks for the help

Comment: The correct way to plot and annotate the dataframe: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih7q2.png) with **`pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`** and using `pandas.DataFrame.plot`.

Comment: A bar plot might be better though: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8afQC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of `annotate` use with your data:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
x = df['pass_att'].values
y = df['pass_cmp'].values
t = df['player'].values
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel('Pass Att')
ax.set_ylabel('Pass Cmp')
ax.set_title('Pass Att vs Pass Cmp')
for i, txt in enumerate(t):
    ax.annotate(txt, xy=(x[i], y[i]), xytext=(x[i], y[i]+0.5), ha='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: Annotate]

Comment: Thanks a million - still learning the basicsII appreciate the help

Comment: Glad to help! Good continuation :)